Remote Login in 24.04 Server Not Working Until User has already Logged In
I have an old PC running Ubuntu Server 24.04 onto which I have installed the ubuntu desktop. I have configured the server so that it boots to CLI.
I have a Windows 11 Laptop that I then use to SSH into this server and which works fine.
I would like to occasionally run a GUI on this server (still learning CLI so sometimes its easier for me) for which I had planned to use RDP from the Windows machine.
To achieve this I:

Start the gdm3 service via SSH to give me a GUI using sudo systemctl start gdm3.service
Open the RDP app in Windows and connect to hostname:port, login using the details configured in Ubuntu the settings for Remote Login
Do what I need, disconnect and stop the GUI using sudo systemctl stop gdm3.service via SSH

The issue is that this approach doesn't work when after a reboot, the RDP client in Windows does not connect. Instead it only works after I have logged in to the Server via the GUI locally. Once I've done this the workflow above runs without issue.
Is there something I'm missing in this setup to enable Remote Login after a boot or is it not intended to function like this?

Also needed to run sudo systemctl start gnome-remote-desktop.
It now functions as intended.
